# WKWebViewのUser-Agent偽装方法について

Tags: swift, xcode, webview

モバイル端末とPC端末で表示が異なるWebサイトをWKWebViewを用いて開きましたが、アクセス元がモバイル端末なので当然モバイルサイトがでてきてしまいます
これをPC用のサイトを開くようなふるまいにしたいのです
そこでUser-Agentを偽装しようと
AppDelegateの didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsに

```
UserDefaults.standard.set("UserAgent" , forKey:"PC Agent")
```

”PC Agent”はPCから取得したUser-Agentです

としてみましたが結果は変わらず、皆様のお力添えをお願いしたいと思い質問いたしました
よろしくお願いします

環境は
Xcode9.2
Swift4.0
iOS11.1
iPhone X
です

追記
コード中にあるUserAgentを調べるWebサイトをWKwebViewで開きcustomUserAgentが変更されているか否かを確認しています
以下のコードでUserAgentの変更を確認しました

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

// adjust SafeArea top space
// portrait のみを想定
var topPadding:CGFloat = 0

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool){

    print("viewDidAppear")

    let screenWidth:CGFloat = view.frame.size.width
    let screenHeight:CGFloat = view.frame.size.height

    // iPhone X , X以外は0となる
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
        topPadding = window!.safeAreaInsets.top
    }

    // Webページの大きさを画面に合わせる,横画面
    let rect = CGRect(x: topPadding,
                      y: 0,
                      width: screenWidth - topPadding,
                      height: screenHeight)

    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    var webView = WKWebView(frame: rect, configuration: webConfiguration)
    let userAgentStr = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.146"
    webView.customUserAgent = userAgentStr

    let webUrl = URL(string: "https://www.baka-ke.com/lab/useragent.php")!
    let myRequest = URLRequest(url: webUrl)
    webView.load(myRequest)

    // インスタンスをビューに追加する
    view.addSubview(webView)
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ずいぶん古い記事を参考にされたのでしょうか?

iOS9以降であれば`WKWebView`に[`customUserAgent`というプロパティ](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1414950-customuseragent)が追加されています。`WKWebView`のインスタンスを生成した直後に値を設定してください。

```
let webView = WKWebView()
webView.customUserAgent = "PC Agent"
```

---

(追記のコードについて)

コメント中に書いた「リクエストを送信しているWKWebViewとcustomUserAgentを設定したWKWebViewが異なる」のパターンですね。あなたのコードでは、`WKWebView`のインスタンスを2回作っています。

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var webView: WKWebView!

// adjust SafeArea top space
// portrait のみを想定
var topPadding:CGFloat = 0

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool){
    //↓ここで`WKWebView`のインスタンスを作って、`customUserAgent`を設定している
    webView = WKWebView()
    let userAgentStr = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.146"
    webView.customUserAgent = userAgentStr

    print("viewDidAppear")

    //...

    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    //↓ここでもう一度`WKWebView`のインスタンスを作っている、さっき`customUserAgent`を設定した`WKWebView`は捨てられる
    webView = WKWebView(frame: rect, configuration: webConfiguration)

    let webUrl = URL(string: "https://www.baka-ke.com/lab/useragent.php")!
    let myRequest = URLRequest(url: webUrl)
    webView.load(myRequest)

    // インスタンスをビューに追加する
    view.addSubview(webView)
}
```

例えば、あなたの`viewDidLoad()`を以下のように修正してみてください。

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool){
    print("viewDidAppear")

    let screenWidth:CGFloat = view.frame.size.width
    let screenHeight:CGFloat = view.frame.size.height

    // iPhone X , X以外は0となる
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
        topPadding = window!.safeAreaInsets.top
    }

    // Webページの大きさを画面に合わせる,横画面
    let rect = CGRect(x: topPadding,
                      y: 0,
                      width: screenWidth - topPadding,
                      height: screenHeight)

    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webView = WKWebView(frame: rect, configuration: webConfiguration)
    //`WKWebView`のインスタンスを生成した直後に値を設定
    let userAgentStr = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.146"
    webView.customUserAgent = userAgentStr

    let webUrl = URL(string: "https://www.baka-ke.com/lab/useragent.php")!
    let myRequest = URLRequest(url: webUrl)
    webView.load(myRequest)

    // インスタンスをビューに追加する
    view.addSubview(webView)
}
```

回答内容を自分のコードに合わせて読み替えるというのは少しハードルが高いのかもしれませんが、「`WKWebView`のインスタンスを生成した直後に値を設定してください。」という記述の後に`let webView = WKWebView()`というコードをお示ししたのは、「この行をあなたのコードの中で`WKWebView`のインスタンスを生成している部分に置き換えて読んでください」という意味だったりします。(そう読めなければダメという意味ではありません。こんな表現なら意図がより伝わりやすくなると思う、と言ったご提案があればお教えください。)

ご提案についてはまた気が向いた時で結構ですので、修正版のコードの方、お試し下さい。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます

そのように設定してみましたが結果が変わらず、
    webView = WKWebView()
    let userAgentStr = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.146 Safari/537.36"
    webView.customUserAgent = userAgentStr
UserAgentをString型で設定するこの形で大丈夫でしょうか？
お手数ですがご教授いただければと思います

Comment: @CiRChaN、ご報告ありがとうございます。こちらは、回答中にあるような文字列リテラルで指定しても、あなたのコメント中にあるように`String`型の変数で指定しても、指定したUser-Agentが送信されるのは(simulatorだけですが)確認しています。・リクエストを送信している`WKWebView`と`customUserAgent`を設定した`WKWebView`が異なる、・リクエストの送信よりも後に`customUserAgent`を設定しているなど、うまくいかない原因は考えられますが、あなたのご質問にはコードがほとんど記載されていないので、確実なことは何も言えません。また「結果が変わらず」とありますが、どのような方法(どのサイトへのアクセス)でどのような結果が得られたのでしょうか? 結果の確認方法などわかれば、何か参考になることが書けるかもしれません。コメント欄は長いコードを書くには不向きですから、ご自身の質問を「編集」して、最後に追記する形で、もう少し詳しいコード全体や確認方法を記載していただけますでしょうか。

Comment: お返事ありがとうございます！　早速コードとテスト方法について編集にて追記いたしましたのでご確認いただければと思います。

Comment: 解決致しました　・リクエストを送信しているWKWebViewとcustomUserAgentを設定したWKWebViewが異なる というところでもう一度ソースを見直したら異なるWebViewにcustomUserAgentを設定しておりました　頂いた情報とアドバイスのおかげです、ありがとうございました！

Comment: @CiRChaN、すでにご自分でお気づきになられたようですが、追記いただいた部分について回答にまとめておきました。ご一読の上おためしください。

Comment: 丁寧な回答ありがとうございました、回答で提示された方法について自分のインスタンス生成部分に読み替えるのは至極普通のことかと思います。私の落ち度ですので気になさらないで下さいませ